# LINQ in Entity Framework 6 with large .Any()

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a EF6 query that takes a list of **IDs** and does a query:

```
public IList<Audit> AuditsByIDs(List<int> ids)
{
    return _db.Audits
        .Include(p => p.User)
        .Where(p => ids.Any(i => i == p.Id)).ToList();
}
```

It works for a **small number of ids**, but when that gets to hundreds I get the error:

> Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply.  Rewrite the
>   query or break it up into smaller queries.

How do I get the query to return only then the **ids** passed in? I can not change the data base :(

Comment: I would use Intersect if it was possible, but it doesn't seem to be :( Could you show us the generated SQL?

Comment: For large data-structures that are being searched by an ID you would prefer some indexed structure like HashSet<int> or Dictionary<int>, would be much faster.

Comment: @Some1Pr0 No, it wouldn't. It's LINQ to Entities, it's transformed into `IN (item1, item2, ...)` as a part of SQL query anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Contains` instead:

```
public IList<Audit> AuditsByIDs(List<int> ids)
{
    return _db.Audits
        .Include(p => p.User)
        .Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id)).ToList();
}
```

Which should be transformed into `IN` within generated SQL query.

Comment: Worked perfectly on the large list. I'll mark as accepted in a few minutes when I am allowed to.

Comment: Size of the list doesn't matter. You should use `Contains` instead of `Any` in such cases no matter how big the list is. It is just better, because generated SQL is better.

Comment: Beware. With sufficiently large lists, Contains will still throw an error.